# Why do we declare a private parameterless constructor every time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, c#-3.0

I have seen this in my projects

```
 class Product
 {
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public decimal Price { get; private set; }
    public Product(string name, decimal price)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
    }
    Product() {}
    public static List<Product> GetSampleProducts()
    {
        return new List<Product>
          {
             new Product { Name="West Side Story", Price = 9.99m },
             new Product { Name="Assassins", Price=14.99m },
             new Product { Name="Frogs", Price=13.99m },
             new Product { Name="Sweeney Todd", Price=10.99m}
          };
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}: {1}", Name, Price);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more information regarding *context*, especially concerning which projects you have seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you create a constructor with parameters, your default parameter less constructor is gone. Now if you want the object to be initialized without providing any values, you will have to declare a parameter less constructor explicitly. It depends on how you want to use it, If you want the object to be initialized only with those values and without them if your object is not valid, then don't add parameter less constructors. But if your constructor with parameters is just a way of initializing the object with some values, you can always initialize your object as below as using C# 3.0 Object Initializer

```
 var product = new Product{Name = "Some Name", Price = 10.0};
```

Answer (score 1):

ORM mappers, deserialization etc. require it for creating objects automatically.

And

```
Product() {}
```

is internal, not private.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of serialization.

If your object does not have a parameterless constructor, then most deserializers which work via reflection will not be able to create instances of the object as it won't know what parameters to pass.

I often make this explicit by adding the Obsolete attribute:

```
[Obsolete("This constructor is for deserialization only", true)]
private Product() { }
```